# saving firebase user to firestore and adding new elements

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a firebase function that is triggered with onCreate method. In this function, I am copying over user data into firestore. Everything works fine, except when I try to add a new element to the user object (even though no errors are thrown) the new firestore document does not show the added element.

Here is my firestore function:

```
    const admin = require('firebase-admin');
    admin.initializeApp();
    const db = admin.firestore();
    
    exports.newUser = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user)=>{
    // create new variable 
        let currentUser = user;
    //add hasSeenProfileUpdate element to the currentUser. This is what I need to add and ultimately save in the firestore
        currentUser.hasSeenProfileUpdate = false;
        return db
            .collection("user")
            .doc(user.uid)
            .create(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(currentUser)))
    
    })
```

The function runs fine and the currentUser is saved to firestore. However the hasSeenProfileUpdate element does not show up in firestore. The console.log on currentUser also doesn't show the new element.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you try refactoring the as in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yd69gqnz/)?

Comment: @Dharmaraj thank you for the reply! can you explain what do you need me to do please? Happy to do whatever it takes to explain better.

Comment: Have you tried refactoring the code shared in the link in my previous comment and running it?

Comment: Thank you @Dharmaraj! I had to make minor modification to it. The user object could not be changed so had to parse out the Json out of it, give it to a variable and do the spread on that constant.

Answer (score 0):

(Thanks to @Dharmaraj) Posting refactored code that works Now:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
const db = admin.firestore();

exports.newUser = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user)=>{
    const currentUser = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(user));
    return db
        .collection("user")
        .doc(user.uid)
        .create({
            ...currentUser,
            hasSeenProfileUpdate: false
          })

})
```